# Lazy loading data from API in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, lazy-loading, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to lazy load content when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the Bootstrap modal, sort of like an infinite scroll, using Vue.js. I'm fetching all my data from a action  method on API call. The data coming from this API is stored in array of objects on mounted and is used in the application.

So far so good. But now I want to implement that in the initial state, only the first 10 items are fetched from the API. When the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page I want to fetch the next 10 results and so on. I've looked at the documentation of the API that I'm using, and it has support for offsetting the items I'm fetching. Though I'm not sure where to start from there. Does anyone know any good resources on this subject? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Before anything say please look at this https://codepen.io/mzolfaghari71/pen/RwbqxVY , it's look for all of the height  ( not modal height ) to scroll,  and render as much as height was , I must render 10 record every time I scroll to bottom of modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a while i solved the problem 
here is my [sample project](https://github.com/mzolfaghari71/VUEjs-Infinite-Scroll) for you reading this question

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution if you are trying to avoid using an npm package. You can use it in any scrollable div in vue. And in the if statement below is where you would handle your api call to fetch more results.

```js
<template>
<div class="scroll" @scroll="scroll">
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
name: "Scroll",
data(){
return{
bottom: false
}
},
methods:{
scroll(e){
const {target} = e;
 if (Math.ceil(target.scrollTop) >=
    target.scrollHeight - target.offsetHeight) {
  //this code will run when the user scrolls to the bottom of this div so 
  //you could do an api call here to implement lazy loading
        this.bottom = true;
        
      }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: For typescript implementation use:

scroll(element: { target: HTMLInputElement }): void {
if (Math.ceil(element.target.scrollTop) >=
        element.target.scrollHeight - element.target.offsetHeight) {
      console.log('YAY')
    }
}